# Proof that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{(-i+1)} < \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-(i+1)} \cdot F_i $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I am Facing a problem when learning about data compression.
I learned that the Fibonacci code for data compression is complete it means it can be represented as complete node tree.
I am trying to prove it using a hint from my professor to use Kraft-McMillan equality.

from Kraft-McMillan equality I get that Kraft of Fib Code is

$ S = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-(i+1)}\cdot F_i $

where  $ F_i $ is the Fibonacci number indexed i

I need help to manipulate ***S*** so that the claim follows

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{(-i+1)} <  S $

---

I tried multiplying by 2 and looking from diffrent angles
all the basic tricks i use to know back in the days but
couldnt manipulate S to proof the claim if you have some insight
please let me know!

---

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A } was missing in the title and caused troubles. Both sums can be computed explicitly, using the formula giving Fibonacci sequence as a linear combination of two geometric series with ratio $(1 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: Is the Fibonacci number in the exponent as in the title or not like it is in the main text?

Comment: as in the main text

Comment: how do i fix it ?

Comment: Part of understanding a problem is being able to communicate it. For example, what is $F_i$?

Comment: sorry  $ F_i $ is the Fibonacci number indexed i

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the $F_i$ in exponent (but if, then it's easy to show, since $F_i \ge 1$).

Otherwise let's use Binet's formula.

$$
S = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{F_i}{2^i} =  \dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{\phi^i - \psi^i}{2^i} = \dfrac{1}{4} \left(\dfrac{2}{2 - \phi} - \dfrac{2}{2 - \psi}\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2} > 1 = 2 \times\sum_{i \ge 0} 2^{-(i + 1)}
$$

Comment: Timur thank you a lot! it looks very elegant! will understand it in an hour and will mark it as the answer

Comment: Timor can you please explain how do you got to $ \dfrac{1}{4} \left(\dfrac{2}{2 - \phi} - \dfrac{2}{2 - \psi}\right) $

Comment: @amberheard just notice that $\sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{\phi^i}{2^i}$ is geometric progression (the same for $\frac{\psi^i}{2^i}$).